# When calling a DLL does extra stack/heap get allocated from the DLL..?

Tags: visual-c++, memory, dll, stack

...or does it share memory with the calling process?  In other words, does the C++ compiler option "stack reserve size" have any effect when compiling a DLL?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Functions use the stack of their caller (which ultimately is determined at thread creation).  Stack reserve size of the initial thread is set by the PE header of the main executable.  Stack size of additional threads is specified by parameters to `CreateThread`.  The PE header of the DLL doesn't affect any of this.

The C++ compiler doesn't have such an option anyway -- which of the many compilation units would control the stack size of the initial thread.  It's a linker option.